# How to run chromium OS under virtual box on MacOS?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, google-chrome-os

I'm trying to make Chromium OS running under VirtualBox on MaxOS. I downloaded image from http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/ and virtual box. But on start, chrome OS does not boot: just black screen.

Comment: If you can...it's better to take the code and built it per your hardware. In your case, I guess it's Intel cpu. BTW, have you tried this: http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/vanilla.php

Answer (score 0):

I've saw my comment... but forgot that I also had this post that should help you to run it on Mac (inside virtual box): http://greenido.wordpress.com/2011/11/10/chromeos-in-virtualbox-test-drive-it/